# R: modify xts matrix for each day series

Tags: r, apply, xts

I have an xts numeric matrix that includes multiple days of minute interval series. I need to calculate statistics for each day on the minute periods, add new columns, and then put all the day series back together.

I have tried apply.daily(), which calls my stats function with an xts matrix, for each day, but I can't figure how to return the modified day series back to the invoking function and reassemble the full set of modified data.

One solution that could work is to use endpoints(x, on = "day") in a loop, then call rbind to reassemble the processed day frames. Is there a better solution?

```
process = function(myxts) {  
  day.indexes = endpoints(myxts, on="days")
  days = length(day.indexes) - 1

  l = list()
  list.index = 1

  for( i in 1:days ) {
    day.begin = day.indexes[i] + 1
    day.end = day.indexes[i+1]
    l[[list.index]] = ets.sym.process.daily(myxts[day.begin:day.end])
    list.index = list.index + 1
  }

  return(do.call("rbind", l))
}
```

Comment: Is the question that you now have a set of daily data which you want to merge in to your minute data (such that all minute bars on 2012-02-28 get the value for 2012-02-28 from your daily data, etc.)? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971797/r-merge-daily-data-with-tick-data/8981517#8981517   (basically: `merge`, then `na.locf`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use some combination of `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(myxts,"days"), myfun))`.  It's hard to be more specific without a reproducible example.